# Encurtar url ao lincar arquivos e páginas com php

Tags: php

Boa tarde, estou precisando de uma ajuda de vocês...quero saber como posso diminuir o caminho da url para lincar arquivos e páginas com php, por exemplo, invés de digitar algo como: site.com.br/view/complements/css/style.css eu queria poder encurtar isso, toda vez que vou linkar uma imagem ou algo assim, o caminho fica gigante, alguém pode me ajudar a proceder?

Comment: Você pode definir uma variável com o link padrão depois só adiciona o que você quer, por exemplo, `$urlPadrao = 'site.com.br/view/complements/';  $imagem = $urlPadrao.'css/styles.css'` ou usar um [`__DIR__`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php)